# react_ga4__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.pageview is not a function

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

was tring to update GA to GA4 for my React project, I am using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4), which gives me some errors as you can see from the title.

```
//import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";
function init() {
  // Enable debug mode on the local development environment
  const isDev = false; // !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
 // ReactGA.initialize(process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID, { debug: isDev });
  ReactGA.initialize(process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID, { debug: isDev });
}

function sendEvent(payload) {
  ReactGA.event(payload);
}

function sendPageview(path) {
  ReactGA.set({ page: path });
  ReactGA.pageview(path);
}

export default {
  init,
  sendEvent,
  sendPageview,
};
```

[image]

had npm installed the package.
checked the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [react-ga4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4) you have to   remove `ReactGA.pageview()` , because it's  **Deprecated** You should  Use `.send("pageview")` instead .

To Send `pageview` with a custom path :

```
ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: "/my-path" });
```